# WinHTTP error 12175 after days and huge amount of queries

Tags: windows, https, winhttp

I am using the Windows WinHTTP library to perform http & https queries, and am sometimes getting a WinHTTP 12175 error, usually after several days of operation (sometimes weeks), hundred of thousandths to millions of queries.

When that happens, the only way to "fix" the error is to restart the service, and occasionally the errors will not go away until Windows (the server) is restarted.

Interestingly enough, this error appears "gradually": getting some of them for some https queries, then after some time, the service gets them for 100% of https queries, then later on, they popup even for regular http queries (the service makes lots of http & https queries, on the order of dozens per seconds, to many servers).
The HTTP connections are made directly, without any proxies. The OS is Windows 2012 R2.

AFAICT there is no memory leak or corruption, outside the 12175 errors, the rest of the service is operating just fine, no access violations or suspicious exceptions, service responds to queries normally, etc.

I have a suspicion this could be related to Windows Update doing OS certificate updates, renewing credentials or something, but I could never positively confirm it.

Anyone else has observed this behavior? Any workarounds?